# Symbols of vectors

Tags: vectors, notation, history

There is a symbol for a vector going out of the paper like this $\odot$ and also for a vector going into the paper like this $\otimes$. Why these symbols are chosen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [historical questions on notation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/are-physics-related-notation-and-terminology-questions-on-topic) should go to [hsm.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One popular answer is to use the arrow analogy. Imagine an arrow is coming directly towards you, you will see the head as a dot. Now imagine the arrow is moving away from you, you will see the tail of the arrow with the feathers making an X. Now vector going out of the plane is just like the arrow moving towards you and vector going into the plane is just like the arrow moving away from you. This is just a convention that scientist agreed upon to make life easier.

Answer (score 2):

The lore I was told was that if one imagines a vector as an arrow (i.e. an object that might be shot from a bow), then one sees the tip of the arrow when it's coming towards you, and the feathers of the fletching as it's going away from you. I don't know if this is the motivation for the choice or something made up afterwards to help us remember.